# Can Reactive Spring Integration work with DLQ?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor, reactor

After reading the following issue [Reactive DSL Error Handling with Flux Channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67737699/reactive-dsl-error-handling-with-flux-channels) I’m still not sure - is there any other way I can stay reactive and yet trigger a DLQ in Spring Integration?

If so, how? Does this require the usage of Direct Channels? Or Flux Channels?

By mentioning the [DLQ pattern](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/DeadLetterChannel.html) I'm referring to error channels, provided by default in Spring Integration. I would like to understand these two concepts:

- How does error handling should work in Reactive Spring Integration? I haven't seen any reference for the [Reactor part of the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/reactive-streams.html), and I haven't seen any reference for Reactor in the [error handling part of the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/error-handling.html). What's the official solution for this?
- Is there an option of using the same functionality of the error handling of regular Spring Integration - e.g. error channels, for Reactive Spring Integration? From the Stackoverflow issue I've mentioned, there isn't such an option. Am I right?

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate more what is your DLQ? There is really no such a notion in Spring Integration. It is better to share with us a specific use-case, so we may help to solve exactly that one. The current question is too abstract and does not reflect reality: since there is no DLQ in Spring Integration, it is hard to see a relevance with Reactive Streams support...

Comment: I've improved the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why is the question and if you really tried that one. Technically it really works same way as it is with regular async endpoint. The `FluxMessageChannel` is subscribed in the `ReactiveStreamsConsumer` which has a `ErrorHandler` option with default exactly for publishing to the `errorChannel` - or headers or global default one.

The algorithm over there is like:

```
protected void hookOnNext(Message<?> value) {
        try {
            this.delegate.onNext(value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            this.errorHandler.handleError(ex);
        }
    }
```

If `handler` is not a `ReactiveMessageHandler`.

We probably need to improve docs for this info: feel free to raise a GH issue.

However it looks like you need to share more info about your use-case. Not sure why you point to that SQS question...